# How do I get a reflection on a property's property in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, specifications

say we have a class with a property subClass.

```
class TestClass(val property: SubClass)
```

The SubClass has its own property

```
class SubClass(val subProperty: Any?)
```

When I only have access to the class itself, I know that I can easily get a reflection to the property via

```
val reflection = TestClass::property
```

However, how do I get access to the subProperty via reflection? The following does not work:

```
val subReflection = TestClass::property::subProperty
```

I'd apprectiate any insight on that! Thanks!

Comment: You just reference it directly from the subclass. `SubClass::subProperty`

Comment: `subproperty` is not a "property's property", as you say in the title; that would be e.g. `KProperty.name` which _can_ be referred to as `TestClass::property::name`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I am using it as a specification for a query for TestClass, so I have to start at TestClass with that.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thanks for the clarification. How should I have worded it correctly?

Comment: @G.Brown Property of the type of property? At any rate I actually misread your question at first; because of the name `SubClass` I thought it extended `TestClass` and didn't see the actual connection between them. So answered it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TestClass::property.returnType.jvmErasure
```

will give you `SubClass::class`, so you can do something like

```
val subReflection = TestClass::property.returnType.jvmErasure.declaredMemberProperties.find { it.name == "subProperty" }!!
```

(`!!` to simplify code, you may want to actually check for null in practice.)

Comment: Thanks, great answer! That is probably the best general solution. When using Spring JPA, there is an even shorter solution, as you can see below.

Comment: Yes, using this only makes sense when you don't know the actual type so can't write `SubClass::subProperty` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer (thanks to @BernhardKern):

```
TestClass::property.toJoin().where(SubClass::subProperty).equal(whatINeed)
```